# Facebook app not showing

Tags: facebook

I have set up an app on my facebook and added the tab successfully. This was working fine until a few days ago when I clicked on the app I was put through to the correct page on facebook but my website page wasn't showing, this has happened on 3 pages that I look after on my account. Below is the link to my app:

https://www.facebook.com/horserugsonline/app_157184554400399

Can someone help please?

Comment: I have now tried placing the facebook url for my app into the address bar when I am logged out of facebook at the app dhows Ok anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: is your app accessible through HTTPS ?

Comment: yes it is accessible through https

Comment: here is the link from facebook, however when you try to access it through the page and the app icon it goes through to te correct url but nothing shows https://www.clearskywebdesignclient.com/hro/facebook.html

Comment: the facebook page is www.facebook.com/horserugsonline

Comment: Here is the facebook url https://www.facebook.com/horserugsonline/app_157184554400399